# Replacing columns of data frame with factor object instead inserts character data?

Tags: r, class, dataframe, r-factor

While trying to plot my data, I found an unexpected behavior which caused my groups to be improperly rearranged and mislabeled.

In short, storing a factor object to several columns of a data frame causes it to be coerced to a character, rather than a factor. This seems related to the [previously-answered question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990437/unexpected-conversion-to-chars-instead-of-factors-in-data-frames-and-matrices) but I still don't understand why it happens.

```
# x is a factor
(x = factor(c("red", "blue", "green")))
class(x)

# make a data frame
frame = data.frame("y"=1:3, "z"=1:3)

# replacing one column at a time yields a factor
frame[,"y"] = x; class(frame[,"y"])
frame[,"z"] = x; class(frame[,"z"])

# however, replacing >1 column at a time yields a character
frame[,c("y", "z")] = x
class(frame$y); class(frame$z)
```

Factors in R tend to cause me the most heartburn, somehow! The ordering, the combination of numerical value and character level, the general fiddliness... Anyway, I'm sure it's something I don't understand about the particular properties of data frames. Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem is in the `[<-.data.frame` function which is what runs when you do an assignment like

```
 frame[,c("y", "z")] = x
```

The problem is that when you specify more than one column as you have, if the new value is not a list, it will convert it to a matrix with the correct number of rows and columns and then split it into a list. So the problem with factors is that you cannot store them in a matrix. you can see this if you try

```
matrix(x, nrow=3, ncol=2)
```

Again, this casting is happening because you are specifying more than one column, and the new value is not a list. So one way around this is to give a list as the new value instead.

```
frame[,c("y", "z")] <- list(x)
```

So, it's a bit annoying that factors are so scared of matrices, but once you learn to master them, they really are a powerful feature of R. Don't be discouraged!

Comment: Ahhh. I'd never realized that R converts the new value (right side of equation) into a matrix and then splits it across the frame (left side of equation). I'd figured that it goes through it sequentially, as a loop would.

I've been using R for about four years now and this stuff still gets me sometimes! I'm glad I'm getting closer to understanding it -- thanks for your help.